# Show drive usage percentage - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Is there a way to see the usage percentage of a HDD from the "My Computer" screen in Windows 7? For example, under the drive where it says "250 GB free of 750 GB" have it say 33% next to it?

Answer (score 3):

Not that I know of but if you view the drives as icons, you should be able to see the little blue progress bar-like indicators and make an educated guess.

If necessary, one can always do a little mental math.